# Adding Elements From Each Row of Jagged Array

Tags: java, arrays, permutation, jagged-arrays

I am trying to get every single combination of elements in a n-row, jagged 2d-array of strings by using only 1 element from each row.

An example array (With each line representing a row in the array):

"A","B","C"

"D","E"

"F","G","H","I","J"

For the above array there would be 30 possible combinations. Recursive solutions are welcome but I would prefer an iterative one for memory usage reasons.

Comment: That are not *permutations* but *combinations*. Since you expect to have only 30 results you don't mix the order of the characters, right?

Comment: Yes, combinations would have been a better word, permutations implies that the order of the strings matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fun little method using modulo:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    iterate(new String[][]{{"a","b","c"},{"d","e"},{"f","g","h","i"}});
}
static void iterate(String[][] jagged) {
    int count = 1;
    int[] divisors = new int[jagged.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < jagged.length; j++) {
        divisors[j] = count;
        count *= jagged[j].length;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String[] combination = new String[jagged.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < jagged.length; j++) {
            int mod = jagged[j].length;
            combination[j] = jagged[j][(i/divisors[j])%mod];
        }
        process(combination);
    }
}
static void process(String[] combination) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination));
    // Do whatever you want here. Process as you go to save memory,
    // or add to a list to process later.
}
```

The heart of it is `combination[j] = jagged[j][(i/divisors[j])%mod];` `divisors[j]` is the product of the earlier lengths, ie the number of combinations possible using the lower-indexed arrays. The `mod` is the length of the current array.

If you'd rather the last element iterate more quickly and the first more slowly, reverse the order when calculating `divisors` / `count`, that is, count `j` down from `jagged.length` to 0.

Comment: Excellent implementation, would have never thought of using the mod operator for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any iterative solution to your problem if `n` is a variable.

The recursive solution:

```
ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
generatePermutations ("", 0);

/** Where the function generatePermutations is defined as: **/

void generatePermutations (String s, int index) {
    if (index >= n) {
        permutations.add(s);
        return;
    }
    for (String a : myJaggedArray[index]) {
        generatePermutations (s + a, index + 1)
    }
}
```